# Cora.ai Dev Board showing that camera is connected even when its not

Tags: google-coral, pycoral

When I run the `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` command in Mendel Linux on my [Dev Board](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board/), it shows:

```
i.MX6S_CSI (platform:30a90000.csi1_bridge):
    /dev/video0
```

even when there's nothing plugged in. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?